# cant connect to remote redis server using lettuce

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

i'm having java spring application, trying to connect to remote redis db.
Im using the lettuce client for this (version 6.0.3.RELEASE),
and 'spring-data-redis' version: 2.4.7.

spring version - Spring Boot v2.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.8.RELEASE
I'm working on mac m1.

This application i'm working on is configured also with jedis (version 3.3.0) with the same redis server and its working fine. server is up responding.

I want to use spring's Cacheable annotation with the same redis server.

problem is - I get error: `org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis`

this is my RedisConfig.java class:

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
     Duration expiration = Duration.ofSeconds(timeToLiveInSeconds);
     RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
                        .builder(factory)        .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(expiration));
        
    return builder.build();
}
    
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setUsername(user);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
    .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
    .shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
    .useSsl().startTls()
    .build();
    
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfig);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    
    return redisTemplate;
    }
```

this is the full error message:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis-advertising-analytics-staging.feedvisor.com:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1230)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:555)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:520)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:402)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.feedvisor.advertising.analytics.service.impl.AdGroupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$228f6459.getAdGroupsData(<generated>)
    at com.feedvisor.advertising.analytics.controllers.AdGroupController.getAdGroupsData(AdGroupController.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.feedvisor.advertising.analytics.config.filter.Slf4jMDCFilter.doFilter(Slf4jMDCFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis-advertising-analytics-staging.feedvisor.com:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:320)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1459)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Connection closed prematurely
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisHandshakeHandler.channelInactive(RedisHandshakeHandler.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.lettuce.core.ChannelGroupListener.channelInactive(ChannelGroupListener.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1114)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:818)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

how can I know what is going wrong ?
host, port, username and password are okay. using TLS.

thanks!!!